# Root Test or Ratio Test for $\sum 2^{-n}e^{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)e^{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}$$

How do I do the root test for this series?

I know that the root test works and that the ratio test does not but how do I show that?

Comment: What ratio do you get, and what $n$-th roots? It should be not too hard to obtain the result from those parts.

Comment: Root test should give you $1/2$; this is conclusive for convergence. Ratio test fails; no limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

For root test,
$$
\sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)e^{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}}
= \frac{1}{2} e^{\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}
$$
and
$$
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0.
$$
@Did points out in the comments that ratio test doesn't work:
$$
\frac{e^{(-1)^{n+1} \sqrt{n+1}}}{2^{n+1}}
\cdot \frac{2^n}{e^{(-1)^n\sqrt{n}}}
= \frac12 \cdot e ^{\displaystyle\left[(-1)^{n+1} (\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}) \right]},
$$
which oscillates between being close to $0$ (for $n$ even) and tending to $\infty$ (for $n$ odd).

However, ratio test will work fine if you split the series up into its even and odd components.

Comment: More precisely, $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} < 1/(2\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Interestingly, the exponential involved in the ratio test is actually $$\exp((-1)^{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}))$$ which has no limit. (The part about the ratio test in  the previous version of this answer was equally wrong.)

Comment: Indeed, many mistakes, thanks @Did